# Is it possible to disable the Htaccess login in a specific page?

Tags: regex, .htaccess

I'm sorry, I dont have any code here, because my question is about Htaccess...
I'm using Htaccess to do the Login on my platform.

But I have some pages, that are allowed to any kind of users, i.e. anyone can access those pages.

I want to know if I can impose access restriction to a specific page only.

Is it possible?

So far, I tried this, but it doesn't work

```
<Files "mypage.php">
    Allow from all
</Files>
```

Thanks

Comment: Yes! What kind of restriction? Allow only for a certain IP address?

Comment: Hey there, following up on this. Did one of the answers solve it for you, or is the question still there? Please give us some feedback. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can restrict access to files for a number of conditions. For instance:

```
**Deny Always**
RewriteRule ^mysecretfile.html - [F]

**Deny Except for a certain IP:**
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^111\.111\.111\.111
RewriteRule ^mysecretfile.html - [F]

**Deny Except for a certain User Agent:**
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} !^MySecretAgent
RewriteRule ^mysecretfile.html - [F]

**Deny Except for a certain Referrer**
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^MyReferrer
RewriteRule ^mysecretfile.html - [F]
```